# After Ejecting from Expo I now get "JSON Value '100%' of type NSString cannot be converted to NSNumber"

Tags: json, react-native, expo, styled-components

I was initially using an Expo Managed environment to develop this app but as it progressed I needed to Eject. After doing so when I run the Debug on the simulator or device I get this error

```
JSON Value '100%' of type NSString cannot be converted to NSNumber
```

Here is a screenshot

[Screenshot of iOS simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01qvD.png)

I was expecting to run as it did in the Expo Managed environment. Also this error only occurs in Debug mode and not Release.

Comment: it looks like you are trying to set a border radius to 100%, this is not a supported value, you should provide a number